# database design : Inventory with multiple item units ( wholesale and retail )

Tags: database, database-design, inventory

I have designed a db for drug ( pharmacy ) store which will sell medicine both wholesale and retail. There are some medicine that can be sold in multiple units, for example, strip, capsule and vial of medicine. Basically, each medicine can be sold in more than one unit. Here is my db:

[image]

I have an inventory_movement records that record the specific stock used to fill each order. if a medicine’s base unit is set to vial, and It has some records with vial in the inventory_movement, and after a period of time, I want to sell that medicine with capsule unit, at this time, how do I record this to the inventory_movement ? And how do I calculate the stocks from inventory ?

If I update the item_unit record to set the data like following:

[image]

And I need to scan whole inventory_mocement table to update the base unit to the new one ( capsule ) and re-calculate the quantity with the multiplier. Is this reasonable ?

Is there any flaws in my design ? Does anyone have any ideas (or examples)?

Answer (score 0):

*"how do I record this to the inventory_movement?"*

Simply book out the whole quantity (in this case 7) with the appr. `unit_id`, then add it back with the other `unit_id`.

*And how do I calculate the stocks from inventory ?*

If I were you, I would set up a new table only for the stocks (f. e. `item_id, unit_id, qty`), and with each movement I would decrease/increase the stock based on the quantity and `unit_id`. For this, I would change the `item_unit` table too like this: `id, item_id, unit_id, multiplier, base_unit (bool)`. And the `item_unit` table would be only a master table, which holds the data, in wich tpye of packaging how many pieces there is.

So, you won't need to go over the movement table and you could calculate your stocks based on the `item_unit` table with the appr. multiplier.